# Count based on multiple grouping variables r

Tags: r, count, dataframe, grouping

I'm just trying to get a count of occurrences of 'stop' in variable (A) for each of 3 grouping variables (B,C,D).

```
A      B  C  D
start  1  1  1
start  1  1  1
start  2  1  2
start  2  1  2
stop   1  2  1
stop   1  2  1
stop   2  2  1
```

Any help would be appreciated - please ask for clarification

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. You could just look at number of rows of `A == "stop"` but I do not this it is the case. Provide a desired output.

Answer (score 2):

I would convert to a `data.table`:

```
DT <- as.data.table(DF)
DT[A == 'stop', lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols=c('B', 'C', 'D')]
   B C D
1: 4 6 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were working in the hadleyverse, you could do this using `reshape2` and `dplyr`. Firstly you would use `reshape` to melt the data so that each of B,C,D has its own row. Then you can `group_by` and `tally` as usual.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

melt(df) %>%
  filter(A == "stop") %>% 
  group_by(variable, value) %>%
  tally()

#    variable value n
#  1        B     1 2
#  2        B     2 1
#  3        C     2 3
#  4        D     1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean each combination of B, C and D? If so here is a base R solution:

```
df <- read.table(text = "A      B  C  D
                         start  1  1  1
                         start  1  1  1
                         start  2  1  2
                         start  2  1  2
                         stop   1  2  1
                         stop   1  2  1
                         stop   2  2  1", header = TRUE)
num.stops <- aggregate((A == "stop") ~ B + C + D, df, FUN = sum)

#   B C D (A == "stop")
# 1 1 1 1             0
# 2 1 2 1             2
# 3 2 2 1             1
# 4 2 1 2             0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%filter(A=='stop')%>%summarise_each(funs(sum),-1)
```